# What exactly does this platformer scrolling code do?

Tags: java, theory, game-physics

I am reading the source code of an existing platformer game and I came accross this:

```
    /* assign the horizontal position of the TileMap on the screen to offsetX
     * this, center aligns the player. */
    int offsetX = width / 2 - Math.round(player.getX()) - TILE_SIZE;
    /* stop the map scrolling if the player reaches the two ends
     * of the map */
    offsetX = Math.min(offsetX, 0); // if offsetX < 0 , offsetX = 0
    offsetX = Math.min(offsetX, width-tileMap.getWidth()); //if offsetX > map width, offsetX = mapwidth

    int offsetY = height - toPixels(tileMap.getHeight()); // not really necessary, I think

    int firstTile = toTiles(-offsetX); // ???
    int lastTile = firstTile + toTiles(width) + 1; // why the +1
```

I have commented some parts I think I understand, and asked questions about others in the comments.

The things that bother me most are:

1- how offsetX is assigned (`width/2 ... ?`) I have understood that it assigns offsetX to some place on the map which center aligns the player, but I have no idea *how*.

2-In the 3rd line, why did the developer write `width - tileMap.getWidth()`?

Note: If it is too troublesome to explain the code line by line, please give me a rough idea, perhaps with a diagram? of what the developer is trying to do here. thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your first question - you say you understand the `width/2` (to center align the player, you're right from what I can tell), and there is no code here that says `player.x = offsetX` which is the "how" I think...

Comment: `player.x = offsetX` is done after this code, sorry I haven't posted it. What i wanted to ask was, how exactly did the formula `width / 2 - Math.round(player.getX()) - TILE_SIZE;` return the horizontal position of the TileMap on the screen which center-aligned the player. I don't understand the theory behind the _formula_ , though I understand what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-i think this offset is for drawing the tiles not for centering the player, this function increases the offset with a negative number when the player moves, the farther to the right he moves, the higher `player.getX()` is, the higher the offset is.

example:

```
width=300
player.getX()=300
TILE_SIZE=10
tileMap[0]=(x,y)=(10,10)

offset=300/2-300-10
offset= -160
```

now this offset is used to draw the tiles with a negative offset, in other words, further left, in this case `tileMap[0]=(10-160,10)`
which means tileMap[0] is out of the screen range(tile scrolled to the left, player to the right)

2-i think this should be  `offsetX = Math.max(offsetX, width-tileMap.getWidth());`
in that case its an extra check to only scroll to the end of the map.

example:

```
    width=300
    player.getX()=900
    TILE_SIZE=10
    tileMap[last]=(1010,10)
    tileMap.getWidth()=1000

    offset=300/2-900-10
    offset= -760
    offsetX = Math.min(-760, 0);
    offsetX = -760
    offsetX = Math.max(-760, 300-1000);
    offsetX = -700
```